# bcp issues with special characters when inserting tables

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I have a text file with special characters

```
#ID^&^DESCRIPTION^&^DATEINS
1^&^This is a test rec^&^12/23/2019 11:31:48
2^&^A Unique identification number (IČO) ^&^10/21/2019 07:36:48
4^&^Test 3 row known as ÖNACE 2020^&^11/02/2009 07:36:48
```

This is the table I created

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TESTtbl](
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [desc] [nvarchar](MAX) collate Latin1_General_CI_AS,
    [DATEINS] [datetime] NULL,
 ) 
 ON [PRIMARY]
```

I built the format file below

```
10.0
3
1       SQLCHAR             0       12      "^&^"      1     cd_val_id                                ""
2       SQLNCHAR            0       0       "^&^"      2     bus_desc                                 SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
3       SQLCHAR             0       24      "\r\n"     3     DateIns                                  ""
```

I don't see the right characters in the table for column "bus_desc". How do I fix this?

This is the bcp command I used

```
bcp.exe DBNAME.[dbo].[TESTtbl] in "c:\temp\some.txt" -T -f "c:\temp\formatfile.fmt"  -C -S"SERVERNAME\INSTANCENAME" -F2 -t "^&^"  -e "c:\temp\err.txt" -o "c:\temp\bcpout.txt"
```

Comment: you should also include the bcp command you are using to load the data.

Comment: Your second field defined in the bcp file ("bus_desc") is set to go into column 3 which is only 24 bytes. You should be missing the DATEINS data as well. The last column of your format file should be 1, 2, 3... not 1, 3, 11. Im surprised that BCP did not fail when you told it to put the 3 column of input data into field 11 of the table. There is no field 11, right?

Comment: @jamie, I corrected format file and added bcp command

Comment: your bcp command does not use the -f option? The -f option is used to specify the location of the format file. Rather than add that as an answer now, can you confirm that that bcp command is really the one you used and also confirm if you really intend to use a format file? I think you are just misusing the bcp command.

Comment: yikes, I had tried with "-c without format file" and "-f formatfile". both didn't work. I updated the bcp command

Comment: Im not following you. If you're not using a format file, then why include the details of a format file in your question. I think I might downvote this question. I dont think you are actually running the commands you are show us? This is getting hard to follow. Sorry brother, I barely have time to help answer questions. even less time to clear up confusing questions.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to load all data into a table and manipulate later. Please find the code below:

```
drop table if exists [dbo].[TESTtbl]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TESTtbl](
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [desc] [nvarchar](MAX),
    [DATEINS] [datetime] NULL,
 ) 

drop table if exists [dbo].TESTtbl_new

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TESTtbl_new](
    [desc] [nvarchar](MAX) 
 ) 

declare @cmd nvarchar(100) = 'bcp DBNAME.dbo.[TESTtbl_new] in "FILE_PATH" -T -c -C 65001 -S SERVERNAME\INSTANCENAME'
exec xp_cmdshell @cmd

select * from [TESTtbl_new]

update [TESTtbl_new]
set [desc] = replace([desc], '^&^', '@')    --assuming actual data wouldn't have '@'

;WITH C AS(
SELECT [desc] AS ID
      ,value 
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [desc] ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) as rn
FROM [TESTtbl_new] TT
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT([desc], '@')t
)
INSERT INTO [TESTtbl]
SELECT [1] AS ID
      ,[2] AS [DESCRIPTION]
      ,[3] AS [DATEINS]
FROM C
PIVOT(
    MAX(VALUE)
    FOR RN IN([1],[2],[3])  
) as PVT
WHERE [1] <> '#ID'

select * from [TESTtbl]
```

**Result:**

[image: Final Result]